# Read entered URL in Chrome Browser in android in Above API23

Tags: android, google-chrome

I want to get url which was typed by user in Chrome Browser, and I am going to check that url with my DB. In API22 and below API's, android allow permission to read those details from Chrome but in API23 and Above they stop those permissions. Kindly give some solution for this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Replace in your gradle.build. It basically changes your target sdk version to 23

```
android {
        compileSdkVersion 23
        buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

        defaultConfig {
            applicationId "com.requestandreceive"
            minSdkVersion 15
            targetSdkVersion 23
            versionCode 1
            versionName "1.0"
        }
        buildTypes {
            release {
                minifyEnabled false
                proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Pls try this.. Target skd version changed.